# Disk doesn't format, chkdsk hangs after "The type of the file system is FAT32"

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, formatting, chkdsk

I bought a brand new USB stick. Because I needed a file on it bigger than 4 GB, I had to reformat it. So I attempted that. The progress bar stood grey for 10 minutes before I gave up.

Assuming something was wrong, I attempted to run a chkdsk on the stick. Nothing happened. It reported that "the type of the file system is FAT32," and went no further. The task manager showed that chkdsk was using no resources. The same thing happened when I attempted to format the drive using "convert".

What's wrong here? Did Walmart sell me trash or is there something I can fix?

Comment: reformat to what file system?

Comment: "The progress bar stood grey for 10 minutes before I gave up." What did you do for giving up? Did you turn it off or something? Sounds like you simply corrupted the disk format by not letting it complete, so reformat it and this time be patient (more than 10 minutes worth)

Answer (score 0):

While I would not rule out Walmart selling you trash, the likelihood is that you did not select "Quick format" when formatting the drive. Since the format did not complete, that is causing chkdsk to fail.

I would try to format it again and check the Quick Format option. If that fails try again without it checked, note; this will take literal hours.

Comment: I did in fact select Quick format. I made sure of that.